# What is value of Docker over Gradle/Maven in Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, maven

Every Tutorial/Guide that I have referred has explained how to build a spring boot application with docker. All those blogs have the same explanation as to why use docker for spring boot application, and it goes something like this

*"A container is a standardized unit of software that assembles code, runtime, dependencies, settings, and initialization in a single package that you can run reliably from one computing environment to another."*

Wasn't Maven/Gradle built for managing the dependencies? How is Docker responsible to assemble code? As far as I know, Spring boot creates a Fat Jar which runs its own embedded container with the specified JRE. The settings (I understand it as config) is taken from the env file.

Why would one containerize the application? What pain point is docker solving and if possible explain with an example.

Thanks in advance.